# SYSTEM UI is not responding error message in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, emulation, haxm

I am facing the same problem. I have ASUS ROG 17 inch Laptop, 16GB RAM, i7 processor, nvidia graphics card 3gb RAM , Windows 7 Home Edition service pack 1, Android studio 3.62, HAXM 7.56, Android Emulator 30.0.5, Android SDK 29.0.6. When I starts my emulator, nexus 6p API 28, Android 9.0, it tooks almost 3 to 4 minutes. and after booting it display message, System UI is not responding,. Wait or close app. When i click wait, it will took a while and starts successfully. But sometimes, It won't. I have to close Android Studio, shut down the system and restart it again. I wondered, why its not working smoothly on such a high configuration laptop.

Comment: Have you configured your emulator yourself ? This error usually happens due to a low memory configuration of the emulator.

Comment: yes.... I configured each and everything myself. when first time I run android studio after installation, it asked me about the amount of RAM i wish to assigned to emulator. IT recommends 2GB RAM and I assigned the same amount of RAM. In the bottom right corner, It shows amount of RAM used by Android studio during execution. Its around 300MB out of 2GB

Comment: Yes, then that's the problem actually this same thing has happened with me also, when I assigned exactly 2GB of RAM to the emultor.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you can't do anything about it. You have assigned 2GB of RAM, but that's too low for the emulator (though it shows that as recommended).

The only way about it is to create and run a new emulator with the default configurations, i.e. don't change anything in the memory or RAM section.

This solution worked for me although the performance of the emulator isn't too good.

Comment: is there any way to change the RAM for emulator? how we create a new emulator?

Comment: Create a new virtual device.